# iPad Drawing: Drawing Images into CGContext

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-graphics, cgcontext

In my iPad drawing app, I have a 768 x 1024 buffer context that I create and use to speed up my drawing.

Here is the code I'm currently executing when drawRect is called that simply copies my already existing drawing onto the screen:

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGImageRef image = CGBitmapContextCreateImage([DrawingState sharedState].context);
CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024), image);
CGImageRelease(image);
```

This code works just as expected: it collects and image from my background context and draws it into my current context, then releases the image.  It works!

However, I'm doing some performance tuning to speed up my drawing and I'm trying this code instead, where "rect" is the rectangle passed in by drawRect

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGImageRef image = CGBitmapContextCreateImage([DrawingState sharedState].context);
CGImageRef subImage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(image, rect);
CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, subImage);
CGImageRelease(subImage);
CGImageRelease(image);
```

This does not work; the image does not appear in the correct location, and may not even be the correct image (can't tell since if the image appears in the wrong location, a portion of the image won't even draw since it will be outside of drawRect's rectangle.)  Any idea what is going on?

Below is how I am initializing the [DrawingState sharedState].context.  This part should be fine, but I figured I'd include it for completeness.

```
if(context != NULL)
{
    CGContextRelease(context);
    context = NULL;
}
if(bitmapData != NULL)
{
    free(bitmapData);
    bitmapData = NULL;
}
if(colorSpace != NULL)
{
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    colorSpace = NULL;
}

CGSize canvasSize = CGSizeMake(screenWidth, screenHeight);

int bitmapByteCount;
int bitmapBytesPerRow;

bitmapBytesPerRow   = (canvasSize.width * 4);
bitmapByteCount     = (bitmapBytesPerRow * canvasSize.height);

colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

bitmapData = malloc( bitmapByteCount );

if( bitmapData == NULL ){
    NSLog(@"Buffer could not be alloc'd");
}

//Create the context
context = CGBitmapContextCreate(bitmapData, canvasSize.width, canvasSize.height, 8, bitmapBytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
```

As requested, the actual optimization I am trying to perform is below.  I am drawing a buffer image (before doing additional drawing) into my buffer context, then later copying my buffer context into the current context.

Original Code:

```
CGContextClearRect([DrawingState sharedState].context, CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024));
if(bufferImage != NULL)
{
    CGContextDrawImage([DrawingState sharedState].context, CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024), bufferImage);
}
```

Optimized Code:

```
CGContextClearRect([DrawingState sharedState].context, rect);
if(bufferImage != NULL)
{
    CGImageRef subImage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(bufferImage, rect);
    CGContextDrawImage([DrawingState sharedState].context, rect, bufferImage);
    CGImageRelease(subImage);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short version of the answer to this question was that I wanted to use CGContextClipToRect instead of trying to get sub images.  CGContextClipToRect(CGContextRef, CGRect) is used to automatically clip any drawing to a context outside the supplied rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you want to use the same `rect` value for creating a sub image and for drawing.

If you read [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGImage/Reference/reference.html), `CGImageCreateWithImageInRect` takes the intersection of the image and the rect parameter, while `CGContextDrawImage` will draw an image into rect.

I don't see how you plan to use this as an optimization but your results sound like what I would expect from your code.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit please?  "image" is an image that is the full size of the screen.  subImage is (supposed to be) the portion of the image where the screen needs to be refreshed.  Then, I "paste" the subImage into the currentContext, based on the rectangle that needs to be refreshed.  Which rect do you think is "wrong" in this scenario?  Also, this isn't the exact optimization I'm trying to do, but I noticed it has the exact same issues as the optimization I'm attempting and is much easier to show others.

Comment: The rect parameter of drawRect: is taken in the local view coordinate space, but your buffer is in screen coordinate space. So you are "cutting" from the wrong buffer. I would suggest looking at the UIView docs "Converting Between View Coordinate Systems". There you can find functions to help you. Specifically, you want to convert the rect you use with CGImageCreateWithImageInRect into screen (window) coordinates.

Comment: My current view is the size of the screen, so I don't think that should be an issue, right?  I've done some logging of the rectangle that is getting passed and the rectangle seems like what I would be expecting to be passed.

Comment: First question is how does this optimize drawing? Second is this from the docs "The portion of the view’s bounds that needs to be updated. The first time your view is drawn, this rectangle is typically the entire visible bounds of your view. However, during subsequent drawing operations, the rectangle may specify only part of your view."

Comment: Yeah, I'm not expecting a 0,0,768,1024 rectangle to be passed everytime.  I'll edit my question to include the ACTUAL optimization, although the code I listed has the exact same issue as the actual optimization but is less complicated and requires less explaining.